# Why is this a line equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Define $$L=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : cz + \overline{cz} + w = 0\}$$

Where $c$ is a nonzero constant.

How does $L$ represent a line?

Comment: Additionally, $w$ should be real. With pproperly complex $w$, the set $L$ would be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$cz + \overline{cz} + w = 0$$
$$2\mathbb{Re}(cz)+w=0$$

If $c=c_1+c_2i$ and $z=x+yi$ then:
$$\mathbb{Re}(cz)=c_{1}x-c_{2}y$$
Replacing:
$$2(c_{1}x-c_{2}y)+w=0$$
$$2c_{1}x-2c_{2}y+w=0$$
Which if $w$ is real represent a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ otherwise is empty.